# Paranoia gem implementation to table with does not have model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-paranoia

Is there a way I can implement Paranoia gem https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia to the table which does not have a model associated with it.

Example: table in DB is test_model, but no test_model.rb

Comment: paranoia is for soft deletion right?what's your case scenario?

Comment: Thanks, @kasperite, yes Paranoia is for soft delete, i have a table in my DB but there is no model associated with it, just wanted to have a soft delete for the records in this table

Comment: how are you gonna handle deletion though?I'm still curious on why you cannot create an associated model here